# Magento 2 How to update SKU after saving product from admin panel?

Tags: magento2, product, event-observer, upgrade, sku

I want to update product sku after save product.
I had used this event :- `catalog_product_save_after` 
In `Observer`,

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $productId = $observer->getProduct()->getId();
            $product = $observer->getProduct();

            $product = $observer->getProduct();       

            $sku = 'TestSku';
            $productFactory = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');
            $otherproduct = $productFactory->create()->load($productId);
            $otherproduct->setSku($sku);
            $otherproduct->save();
       }
   }
```

But while saving product, it gives

> No Data Found Error
>   [image]

Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not update because you are using `catalog_product_save_after` event. So, on product save again event will be call. So, You can use `controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after` or `catalog_product_save_before` event and You can update SKU like this below code :

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // you will get product object
        $_sku=$_product->getSku(); // check here you get sku or not.
        $_product->setData('sku','test');
        $_product->save();

    }   
}
```

Comment: I tried all the possible ways including this, actually save function is not working here, Is there any other way to update product sku after save product?

Comment: Please check my updated answer and change your events.

Comment: It worked , Thanks

Comment: Happy to Help :) Happy coding !!

Answer (score 1):

catalog_product_save_before
use this event but dont call save function

Comment: To update sku, I need product id aswell. because in new sku I am going to give product id. But in before event I will not get product id.

Comment: you will get the id check it once

Comment: It worked with this event: controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after, thanks for help.